# link posts to custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type 'books' which I store different custom fields of information about books.

I want to use posts and link the posts I write (in categories such as news, or offers) to the books.

For example, when the user is viewing the book information page, I want to be able to display all the posts in news category related to that book.

I was able to do this using a custom field and assigning the book id to the news. But what if I have a news that's related to a lot of books?

Is there any way to file all the Custom Post titles to a taxonomy? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Creating these links and displaying them on any desired page with a widget or shortcode can be easily done with a plugin called Sub Posts. It's not a free plugin, but it will do exactly what you're asking. You can find more information at [www.subposts.com](http://www.subposts.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Posts to Posts Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/)

This plugin allows you to create many-to-many relationships between posts of any type: post, page, custom etc. A few example use cases:

- manually curated lists of related posts
- post series
- products connected to retailers
- etc.

Additionally, you can create many-to-many relationships between posts and users. So, you could also implement:

- favorite posts of users
- multiple authors per post
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your functions.php file, you can register a new taxonomy and related with your custom post type, for example

create a custom post type:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

```
register_post_type('books',
      array(
        'labels' => array(
          'name' => __('Books', 'sc'),
          'singular_name' => __('Book', 'sc')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'books'),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail')
      )
    );
```

Create a custom taxonomy (similar to categories)
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

```
register_taxonomy(
      'gender',
      'books',// your custom post name
      array(
        'label' => __('Gender', 'sc'),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'gender' ),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'show_in_quick_edit' => false,
        'meta_box_cb' => false,
        'show_in_menu'=>true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
      )
    );
```